# xsel copying text to clipboard but trys to execute the string when I paste into terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, clipboard

I want to copy some text I've constructed to the clipboard. I use xsel to this as follows:

```
echo "my text" | xsel -b
```

And now the string "my text" has been copied to my clipboard. However when I paste it into the terminal I get the following error:

```
bash: my text: command not found
```

It seems it is trying to execute the string. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's likely because echo appends a newline. To avoid this, use printf:

```
printf "my text" | xsel -b
```

This works for me under Cygwin with bash and pasting with <kbd>shift-insert</kbd>.

Interestingly, pasting under zsh doesn't automatically execute the newline.